# Error en uso de FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

estoy trabajando con FPDF en localhost, tengo este problema que la verdad no entiendo el porque, simplemente tengo una clase llamada informe donde esta como el diseño de como se vera el PDF. Pero a la hora de pedir el informe, sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi clase:

```
<?php

require('fpdf.php');

class informe extends FPDF {

    function Header() {

        $this->Image('../../img/logo.png',10,10,30);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',20);
        $this->SetTextColor(48, 59, 90);
        $this->Cell(1);
        $this->Cell(0,70,'CEDESOFT',0,0,'L');
        $this->Ln(45);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',14);

    }

    function Footer() {

        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I', 8);
        $this->Cell(0,10, 'Pagina '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C' );

    }
}
```

Aqui esta el archivo que trae a listar todo:

```
<?php 

include 'fpdf.php';
include_once '../gestiociudades/modelo_ciudades.php';

$ciudad = new Ciudades();
$lista = $ciudad->listar();

$pdf = new informe();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFillColor(255, 207, 17);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'ID',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(40,6,'NOMBRE_CIUDAD',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Cell(40,6,'PAIS',1,0,'C',1);

$pdf->SetFillColor(224, 235, 255);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);

foreach ($lista as $value) {

    $pdf->Cell(20,6,$value['id'],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(40,6,utf8_decode($value['nom_ciudad']),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(40,6,utf8_decode($value['pais']),1,0,'C');

}

$pdf->Output();

 ?>
```

Alguna razon deporque dice que no encuentra la clase informe?

Comment: tu clase informe esta en el archivo modelo_ciudades.php ?

Comment: No, es un archivo independiente

Comment: pues debes incluirlo, con un include_once

Comment: Listo, tuve que eliminar el include de fpdf y agregar el include_once con la clase